# execute erb function only on onclick event

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying to build a ruby on rails app where a button click would call a specific function. i put the function in a helper module and I am calling the function with the onclick event. my issue is that it seems like teh ERB code is run anyway, even when I do not click the button. I tested the button by replacing the call to the function by an alert which works properly, only popping up when I click the button, but it seems like that mixing erb inside html makes it run automatically. I also tried to pass through an intermediary step by adding a javascript function called by the onclick event, but it does not solve my issue as the code is run anyway.

**index.html.erb**

```
<input type="button" name="test" value="Charger en masse" onclick="<%charger_photos%>">

module CartephotosHelper
  def charger_photos
    @test=Array.new
    Dir['./public/images/*'].each do |file_name|
      @test.push(file_name)
      next if File.directory? file_name 
    end
  end
end
```

test by using javascript to call the fucntion outside of the onclick event

**index.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function chargermasse(){ 
    <%charger_photos%>
  }
</script>
<input type="button" name="test" value="Charger en masse" onclick="chargermasse()">
```

Comment: nice try, but you can't call a Ruby function from Javascript like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`erb` is Embedded RuBy, which is run on the server and `javascript` is run on the client (ex: browser). You are trying to run the `erb`, which is a server side code, on the client. It doesn't work.

What you need to do is, on the client side, the `onClick` event should call server, gather those results and update the `dom` with those results.

Refer to [working_with_javascript_in_rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The helpers are linked to you models not your controllers, so you have to include the helper on your controller

```
Cartephotos_controller < ApplicationController
   include CartephotosHelper
end
```

and them you may call the function from the erb simply by callyng

```
<% charger_photos %>
```

Comment: in fact i added the include CartephotosHelper abd the call is workign, my issue is that it is always run as i would it to run only when i click on the button