# How to call a function from ruby-on-rails (HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, function

Let, I have a button:

```html
<button type="button" onclick = "myfunction()" class="collapsible">Expand content</button>
```

And, I have a JavaScript function:

```js
function collapse() {
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
                content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                content.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Usually, we call a JavaScript function in HTML using `onclick`. What if it comes to Ruby-on-rails? I noticed that I can't call a function that way in Ruby-on-rails. How to call a function from ruby-on-rails (HTML)?

[image: Preview]

[image: Preview]

Comment: Aren't the rails Ruby travels on on the server?

Comment: @Teemu Yes! It is..

Comment: Then you've to submit a form or send an AJAX request, click a link etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [execute erb function only on onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713855/execute-erb-function-only-on-onclick-event)

Comment: @Teemu I have a button. If I click on that button than, a div class will be shown. If I click on that button than, that div class will be collapse. If you look at my JS code than, you may understand...

Comment: Why to mess with the server-side code at all then?

Comment: @Teemu Sorry! I have lot of Javascript code in assets.. And, I am trying to call a function of JS from HTML.. I said `ruby-on-rails` cause, usually we use `onClick` method to call a JS function. But, that's not working while backend is `ruby-on-rails

Comment: Maybe you don't need JS at all, see [details element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

Comment: I imagine the problem is that you are using Webpack to handle the JS and your function is not exposed in the global scope. You can define the function in the window object instead so you can call it from anywhere like `window.collapse = function() {...}`

Comment: @arieljuod Could you pls write an answer? I am beginner in ruby-on-rails. I didn't understand you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new Rails applications, JavaScripts assets are handled by Webpack (through the Webpacker gem). Webpack, by default, isolates function inside the files that are defining the function, so the functions do NOT polute the global scope (the window object in a web).

If you want the browser to be able to run a function when clicking a button, you have many options, in your case you are using the `onclick` attribute which will be run in the global scope so it will try to execute the function in the window object.

Since your function is actually isolated, the browser can't call it, so a solution is to make the function global instead of isolated.

To do that, instead of doing this:

```js
function collapse() {
    ...
}
```

you can define the function as:

```js
window.collapse = function() {
    ...
}
```

That way, the function will be available in the global scope and you can call it from any place.

Though now that I read your code better, you have a weird mix of concepts there, you have `onclick="myFunction()"` but you are not defining `myFunction` anywhere, and then inside the `collapse` function you are adding eventlistener to the buttons... again? the problem doesn't seem to be the onclick in your button, but the `collapse` function never being called to actually attach the event listeners.

I would do something like:

```js
function collapse() {
    ...
}

collapse() // call the function so it attaches the event listeners
```

and then you don't need the `onclick` in your button.